# Need a formula that looks at the first digit or letter in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have a column of numbers.  Some begin with the digit 8 and the rest begin with other digits.  I want to write a formula that will return "2" if the number in column A starts with 8, and "1" if the number in column A starts with a number other than 8.

Is this possible and if so, how please?

Answer (score 13):

Using a combination of the Left and If functions...

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1) = "8", 2, 1)
```

That's assuming you want to number returned as a number... if you want it as a string..

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1) = "8", "2", "1")
```

Comment: This is fantastic!  I've been searching all day for this.  Can you please explain what the "1" after the A1 does?

Comment: @Prebanks it's the number of characters you want returned starting with the left-most character in the cell. The function syntax is `LEFT(text, number of characters)`.

Comment: Ian, thank you so much for your help. You've saved the day!

Comment: And Brett you too ~ thank you for your quick response!